# Ansible - List all object attributes from dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to obtain an attribute from all the objects in a dictionary and add that attribute to another dictionary or group. My problem is the number of objects is dynamic.

I gather facts from all running ec2 instances with a Unique ID tag as a variable and register the dictionary output as a variable: info

tasks:
  - name: Gather facts about running EC2 Instances
    ec2_remote_facts:
      region: "{{region}}"
      filters:
        instance-state-name: running
        "tag:UID": "{{UID}}"
    register: info

For each object I want to pull the id attribute. I am able to accomplish this if I designate the object (instances).

debug: msg={{info.instances.0.id}}
debug: msg={{info.instances.1.id}}

Is it possible to pull 'all' and not have to designate specific objects in the dictionary and add the values to a group? Am I maybe thinking about this wrong and there's a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I wrote the fact gathering into a role. and was able to use a with_items loop on the facts that came back registered from the role. – tmwheez just now   edit